# JMeter variable as regular expression to extract value from JMeter variable

Tags: regex, jmeter

I wanted to check a Jmeter variable which is subset of another jmeter variable. tried to use regular expression extractor. if ${SKUID} is substring of ${items}, then SKU_UNIQUE contains ${SKUID}. else, SKU_UNIQUE contains SKU_NONREPEAT. But, looks ${SKUID} is not resolving it's value in regular expression field

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMeter variable should be as is -`items` and Template `$1$` for first match